# Extra space showing in end url

Tags: django-views

I am having an issue with Panda. I am trying to add a new views to my website and when I type this line in the product/urls.py file I get an error stating that the endpoint was not found by Panda - Page not found (http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/new/)

Using the URLconf defined in pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
products/
**products/ new**
The current path, products/new/, didn't match any of these.

I have created a new function to hold the new products view

```
def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Product')
```

Then I have mapped the endpoint in the products/urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    **path('new', views.new)**

]
```

P.S. The index is behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

The space is just formatting to show that these is a set of suburls. The problem is the trailing slash:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new/', views.new)
]
```